# jQuery .on trigering multiple times

Tags: jquery

I am using this code into my page. When i click on the button with .process_record class  it gives me a single alert but if i again click on the same button it gives me 2 alerts at a time. I don't know why its behaving like that.

```
$(".body .content").on("click", ".process_record", function(e){

        alert("clicked");
        var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
        $.post(url, function(data){
            $(".body .content").html(data);
        },"html");
    })
```

Comment: What is being appended in your `$.post`? Probably causing this.

Comment: most likely you're binding it again each time you click it, so each successive click results in an additional click event being triggered per click.

Comment: It seems because the content which gets loaded through $.post also has a button with the same class. I want to perform the same action through that button to that's why im using .on method.

Comment: At what point do you execute this block of code? It should only once per page load (usually in your document.ready event). As @KevinB says, you may be rebinding the event, but I don't see that happening in this click handler.

Comment: Thank you because the same function was also added in the page which is being loaded via $.post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/z9VFA/

This works properly for me in the above fiddle. The html is set up as:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="content">
        <input type="button" class="process_record" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My guess is that you are setting the handler multiple times, perhaps within another click event. From your comments, you may be executing the binding again from a script tag you are injecting from your other page when you ajax load it. You could likely solve this by moving script tags into an external file on your other page, and then when you go to inject it make sure only load the body tag, not the head or scripts.

The code solution is to have your events unbind and rebind themselves on click, to be sure there is only one handler on each:

http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/B5UPB/

```
var clickAction = function(){
    alert("clicked");
    $(".body .content").unbind("click");
    setClick($(".body .content"),clickAction);
}

var setClick = function(target,action){
    target.on("click", ".process_record",action)
}

setClick($(".body .content"),clickAction);
```

keep in mind that this will unbind ALL events from `$(".body .content")`, so if you want to only unload the named event, change the unbind line to `$(".body .content").unbind("click",clickAction);`